How to get a fabric.js IText object from JSON representation of the IText object?
I have a JSON object that represents an IText object, which I've got from canvas JSON representation. I want to be able to make this text field active, or get the text field itself as an IText object. I can't find anything related to my question on the web. Is that even possible in fabric.js?

Can you share some examples and the minimal code to reproduce it
